# After 301 move I have lost previous positions on Google

Tags: redirect, 301-redirect

I moved my site recently from brandonwang.org to brwang.com. I went online and found this lovely snippet of code (below) and modified it a bit.

This is my .htaccess file in it's entirety for brandonwang.org:

```
# This allows you to redirect your entire website to any other domain

Redirect 301 / http://brwang.com/

AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Very interestingly this morning I Googled myself and it turns out I am no longer in the search results! This suggests that **I have lost my search rankings** and previous position. Whyyyy?

1. I am interested in knowing why I have lost my ranking and position.
2. I am interested in knowing, if I can, how I can fix this problem.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: new domain is first on the list if I google your name. You might be on a bit of a out of sync google datacenter. They aren't synced in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this information in Google Webmaster Help:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=61ba61b293042e69&hl=en

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=1d5d4b76fac8fde2&hl=en

Basically, your site will be fine in a few weeks once the Google Bot has found all of your 301 redirect links.  I always thought that the search results would be preserved unless the Google Bot actually found missing links, but apparently it's more compliicated than that.

The important thing to remember is that any links you built up from other sites linking to you **will** eventually be recrawled by Google.  In summary, you can breathe a sigh of relief :)

Answer (score 0):

[Google webmaster central](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93633) certainly indicates this is a valid thing to do.

I tried a wget of your old domain and it does appear to 301 redirect correctly:

```
$ wget http://www.brandonwang.org
--2011-01-19 19:38:28--  http://www.brandonwang.org/
Resolving www.brandonwang.org (www.brandonwang.org)... 199.27.135.100, 199.27.134.100
Connecting to www.brandonwang.org (www.brandonwang.org)|199.27.135.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://brwang.com/ [following]
--2011-01-19 19:38:29--  http://brwang.com/
Resolving brwang.com (brwang.com)... 199.27.135.100, 199.27.134.100
Connecting to brwang.com (brwang.com)|199.27.135.100|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `index.html'
```

so everything looks ok as far as I can tell.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Thanks. Then why is this happening? Any ideas? Google "brandon wang"; LinkedIn, my blog, and then a link to my webpage with a tracking code on it rank higher than my actual site! It wasn't like this before; what happened?

Comment: Sorry no idea. :(